# Facebook Adnetwork stopped working even though SDK upgraded to 4.26

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.x

We have added this command in build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'
```

Still, we are getting an error in FB portal saying "Ensure that most of your ad traffic is coming from SDK 4.23 or above (4.22 for Unity)" 
Screenshot from FB portal showing the error is also pasted below for more reference

[image: error reported in FB portal]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This error should be gone once most of the traffic is going to the newer app version, where the newer SDK is used.

Even though you updated the app, probably still more users use older version. Wait a couple of days, once most of your users update the app and majority of them use the newer version, the warning will be gone.

Comment: I saw the stats in FB portal and it seems that most traffic is coming from the newer app version. Is there a way through which i can fetch the SDK version of FB so that I could run some tests at my end and actually check what is the version that is being used at run time

Comment: @saunlogan, not exactly sure, but maybe you can see the SDK version in logcat output.

As for the warning in the FAN page, for me it was gone couple of days after I've released an update to the app with the newer SDK.